# How much time does MySQL need to build an index

Tags: mysql

How much time does MySQL need to build an index of a table with 30,000,000 entries that are strings of length 256?
At the moment it seems to take hours and I don't know how long I should wait till I conclude that MySql simply failed at building an index.

Comment: This would depend on the hardware of the machine that it's running on, but I'd imagine it would take quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may run `SHOW PROCESSLIST \G` in mysql console to watch its state. I had a similar problem just a couple of hours ago, but my table was much smaller.

Here a list of [thread states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/general-thread-states.html) you will definitely need. After an hour of waiting I realized that `ALTER TABLE CREATE INDEX` is in `Locked` state, I needed to restart mysqld and run the statement once again. That time I had index built in 15 minutes.

By the way, I recommend to run index creation from mysql console, GUI tools may add some spices to the process.

Answer (score 0):

it could easily take hours. it all depends on the machine specs, load, etc etc. to see whether it's failed, check something like `top` or watch your hard drives - if they're going mad it's still indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS you may check for disk activity (i.e. does it reads/writes DB files) to find out if it failed or not.